# Join two tables based on different column type

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, join, hive

I have two tables with the following schema as example:

```
   scala> df1.printSchema
   root
    |-- id: string (nullable = true)

   AND

   scala> df2.printSchema
   root
    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
    |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to get all col1 in df2 where an element in col2 array is equal to id in df1. Something such as df3 is output:

```
   scala> df3.printSchema
   root
    |-- c1: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
    |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
```

where df3.c2 is basically df1.id and df3.c1 is array of all df2.col1 that satisfy the mentioned equality.

any SQL (hive) or Scala solution is very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hive:

```
select collect_set(df2.col1) as col1, df1.id as col2
 from df1
inner join 
(
select --explode col2 array 
      col1, s.c2 as col2 
 from df2 lateral view explode(col2) s as c2 
) df2 on df1.id = df2.col2
group by df1.id;
```

Comment: when I add a partition to this query as following:                                                                               "from df2 lateral view explode(col2) s as c2"  => "from df2 where partition='blah-blah' lateral view explode(col2) s as c2" I get the following error: FAILED: ParseException line 8:90 missing ) at 'as' near 'c2'... Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3520791 put the where after lateral view.  lateral view explode(col2) s as c2 where partition='blah-blah'

Comment: *****WORKED!***** Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a subquery for this:

```
select collect_set(df2.col1) as col1, df1.id as col2
from df2 lateral view
     explode(col2) s as c2 join
     df1
     on df1.id = s.c2
group by df1.id;
```

Comment: This fails due the following error: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10085]: Line 3:5 JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported 'c2'